# XML transformation using XSL and getting source element name as XML values

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to convert the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
```

The target XML that I require is something like this:

```
<params>
<param>
<key>title</key>
<value>Empire Burlesque</value>
</param>
<param>
<key>artist</key>
<value>Bob Dylan<</value>
</param>
<param>
<key>country</key>
<value>USA</value>
</param>
<param>
<key>company</key>
<value>Columbia</value>
</param>
<param>
<key>price</key>
<value>10.90</value>
</param>
<param>
<key>year</key>
<value>1985</value>
</param>
</params>
```

What should the XSL file look like for me to be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <params>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cd"/>
        </params>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd/*">
        <param>
            <key><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></key>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
        </param>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**II. Output**

```
<params>
    <param><key>title</key><value>Empire Burlesque</value></param>
    <param><key>artist</key><value>Bob Dylan</value></param>
    <param><key>country</key><value>USA</value></param>
    <param><key>company</key><value>Columbia</value></param>
    <param><key>price</key><value>10.90</value></param>
    <param><key>year</key><value>1985</value></param>
</params>
```